# How do I delay the start of some clouds on this webpage?

Tags: html, css, web, css-animations, frontend

I'd like to delay some clouds from starting on http://therealrohanm.me/Falcon-Hacks-Website/, neither animate delay nor transition delay seem to work. How would I accomplish this?

View the code here: https://github.com/Meeshbhoombah/meeshbhoombah.github.io

Comment: One possible way would be to add the img tags to your animated-cloud-background div with a delay / setTimeout. So when the page loads, you only have one or two clouds and use javascript to append more img tags as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0cmonc5q/

```
#animated-cloud-background .cloud.cloud-1 {
    top: 10%;
    -webkit-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
    animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65);
    z-index: -5;

    animation-delay: 2s;   
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;

}
#animated-cloud-background .cloud {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -128px;
}
```

The animation delay is working, but it needs to be placed after the animations for your style.. Problem with this is that it also delays the first frame, So it appears on the screen until the delay has happened. I've fixed this by giving the cloud elements a -left position.. in this case 128 the width of the image.

And this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0cmonc5q/1/

Shows each image having a different delay (1 to 5 seconds), i've given them all the same animation time/rate so they all move but shows the delay in effect.

Comment: Someone else may have a cleaner / better solution as css animations i rarely play with. But the above does work as a solution.

Comment: Works perfectly, I see no problems.

Comment: Glad i could be of help